# SQL Trigger Executes Only Once

Tags: sql-server, email, triggers

We are attempting to write a trigger that emails upon insert/update. This needs to run every there is a change. The current trigger only runs once and then will not run again. 
Here is the code:

```
USE db
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER emailonupdate
ON table
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
Begin
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @BODY NVARCHAR(MAX) = N' '; 
    SELECT @BODY += CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + RTRIM(inserted.col1 + ' has added an item in db to ID# ' + inserted.col2) FROM inserted
    WHERE inserted.col1 IN (1263, 1276, 1277);

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted WHERE col1 IN (1263, 1276, 1277))
    BEGIN
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
          @profile_name = 'DBA_Notifications',
          @recipients = 'me@myemail.com',
          @subject = 'Database Email', 
          @body = @body;
    END
End
```

Comment: Please update with your DBMS tag (eg; sql server, postgre, mysql..etc)

Comment: What do you mean it runs only once? I guess you want it to run for every row you update or insert, and doesn't matter if you modify or insert lots of rows or only one?

Comment: What is the structure of the table? Here you mentioned a WHERE clause. Will this always insert the same values mentioned in the WHERE clause each time?

Comment: @Bartosz Siemasz : Only runs once = when conditions are met (new record(s) are inserted) it will send the email notification. The next time conditions are met (not associated to the first instance, but new record(s) are inserted it does not send the email.
Yes, we want it to run regardless if multiple rows are inserted or only one, but more importantly we want it to send the notification every time records are inserted.

Comment: @GopakumarN.Kurup : there might be other values that are inserted (which we do not want notifications of), but when the values are in fact the same and meet the requirements of the WHERE clause, it will only send the email notification once. These values are controlled  via the application passing the information to the DB (and do not change).

Comment: @ernft I don't see any issues in your Trigger. Can you please replace the MAIL part with a print statement and test it whether it is working fine? May be the issue will be with the DBMAIL.